# The '-i' flag in expect

Tags: expect

In the [page that describes Expect](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html), it is written:

> For example, the following example waits for "connected" from the
>   current process, or "busy", "failed" or "invalid password" from the
>   spawn_id named by $proc2.
>
> ```
> expect {
>     -i $proc2 busy {puts busy\n ; exp_continue}
>     -re "failed|invalid password" abort
>     timeout abort
>     connected
> }
> ```

As far as I understand, everything in that expect is relevant only to the *spawn_id* named by `$proc2`, while the current *spawn_id* isn't relevant.
That's because that the `-i` flag (as written prior to the first quotation):

> ... declares the output from the named spawn_id list be matched
>   against any following patterns (up to the next -i).

Perhaps the code is not written as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dor, I checked THE Expect book ([Don Libes's "Exploring Expect"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565920902)) and you are correct.

If the -i flag is used in an expect block, then everything within that block will attempt to match the output from the spawned process with the id indicated after -i.

So, according to Don Libes, what that page says is wrong. And I would go with Don Libes on this one.  :-)

Maybe you can report it to them so they can fix it?

Comment: I've sent an email to `webmaster@-SPAM-.tcl.tk` (Omitting the string `-SPAM-.`)